# prevent column break on a block of text?

Tags: css

I am trying to prevent the following block of text to break, forcing "blue package" to the right column.[image]

HTML is this:

```
<h2 class="blue">Blue Package:</h2>
<p><strong>Thurs.</strong> $425.00 <strong>Friday-Sun</strong> $475.00</p>
<ul>
    <li>Party length:  2 hours</li>
    <li>12 guests. </li>
    <li>Each  additional child: $12.00</li>
    <li>1.5 hours of  creative building time in our building studio</li>
    <li>Enjoy pizza  or bagels for 12 children (plus the birthday child) in our party room</li>
    <li>Beverages</li>
    <li>Paperware</li>
    <li>Invites</li>
    <li>Thank yous</li>
    <li>12 mylar  balloons</li>
    <li>Builder&rsquo;s  certificates for each guest</li>
    <li>Favors: Lil&rsquo; Builders  12 oz. cup filled with your child&rsquo;s unique Lego creation or random Legos
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've done it before on a whole paragraph using the following CSS, but if I put the same CSSstyling on the h2 tag, it will not force just the h2 to the second column.

```
 p {
-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
-moz-column-break-inside: avoid;
-o-column-break-inside: avoid; column-break-inside: avoid; display: table; }
```

Any ideas to get this whole block of text to move over?

Comment: Have you tried to put the whole block in a wrapper and give your css rules to this wrapper?

Comment: how is your css currently divided into two columns?

Comment: yes I tried this and it did not work, I see no change: http://jsfiddle.net/kimwild/4ujJc/

Comment: columns are created like this #main-container #main-inner-container-bottom article#two-col {
 display: block;
 overflow: hidden;
 -moz-column-count: 2;
 -moz-column-gap: 25px;
 -webkit-column-count: 2;
 -webkit-column-gap: 25px;
 column-count: 2;
 column-gap: 25px;
}

Comment: The jsfiddle does not demonstrate anything, because it contains nothing but the wrapper, no content before or after.

Comment: add a linebreak(<br />) after orange?

Comment: Please provide enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry yes wrapping it in a div appears to have worked. It moves it to the second column. I have another question, is it possible to force this to stay in the first column? Thanks! http://jsfiddle.net/kimwild/4ujJc/

Comment: Also, Presto (Opera) does not use prefixes for the *column* properties.  http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn

Comment: In response to my question above asking if this can stay in the first column, is all browsers it appears in the second column but in Opera it appears in the first column, and in IE it seems it is not recognizing the columns at all?

Comment: You have no control over which column an element goes into.  Each browser has their own algorithm for determining this.  Generally speaking, they will try to equalize the contents.  If equalization is not possible (due to breaks, etc), then the last column will usually be the shorter one.

Comment: OK thanks @cimmanon - any ideas why IE isn't recognizing this at all? It is not applying the column break. I am view it in IE 10 http://lilbuilders.com/pages/packages.htm

Comment: It seems adding break-inside:avoid; fixes the IE problem. IE wasn't recognizing column-break-inside break-inside:avoid;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The right property is actually [`break-inside`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh772193%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but is not well supported by browsers apart from Internet Explorer 10. I've heard that using `page-break-inside` will work in Firefox (Gecko), but not always.

```
p, ul {
    -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; /* Chrome, Safari */
    page-break-inside: avoid; /* Firefox */
    break-inside: avoid-column; /* CSS3, IE10+ */
    /* display: table; */
}
```

Comment: thanks! I made a comment above that I added this to the css and it fixed the IE issue.

Comment: I want to break the page *before*, not avoiding it altogether. How does this help? It seems to be this isn't the right answer, because breaking before the element doesn't seem to be supported in Firefox yet.